# As Firebase rules are not filters, how do we filter?

Tags: android, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am trying to have a set of **chats** that contains a list of **participants**, and be able to query per user, its list of **chats** where the user is a **participant**.

Because filtering is not possible in Firebase on the server side (I guess for scalability), I understood that I have to prepare all the data in a resource for each form of "filtering" I need, so I have the following structure right now:

[image: database structure screenshot]

Those are the rules I wrote to secure the data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        "$user_id" : {
        "chats" : {
            ".read":"auth != null && $user_id == auth.uid", 
            ".write": "auth != null && !data.exists()"
        }
      }
    },
    "chats": {
      "$chatId": {
        ".read":"auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('chats').child($chatId).exists()",
        ".write": "auth != null && !data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The first rule (/users/&user_id/chats) is OK and works as intended. I am able to query by user_id and get a map of all the chat_ids the user should have access to.

The second rule fails because what I thought I had was the **chat_id** but what I really have is the id for the object containing an attribute having the chat_id as **uid**, and I can't get to a child without knowing its ID, as **[rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter)**.

The only way I see I can protect a chat is to have a string for a list of participants, and then use contains() on that child of a chat to block access to it if the user is not a participant of that chat.

Is there another way? Is it the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing new key to set the chat's id in the "uid" key, you can directly set the chat's key as the child under `/users/<uid>/chats` with `true` as the value.

```
{
    "users": {
        "<uid>": {
            "chats": {
                "<chat_id>" : true,
                "<chat_id2>" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this structure, your firebase database rules for the read access should be true for the correct user.